# how to create a python object where every attribute is None

Tags: python, oop, python-object

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I would like an object where you can query any attribute, and it just returns None, instead of an error.

eg.

```
>>> print(MyObject.whatever)
None
>>> print(MyObject.abc)
None
>>> print(MyObject.thisisarandomphrase)
None
```

without manually assigning all of these values in the object's __init__ function

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you tell us why you want to do this?

Comment: I'm making a spreadsheet and I want the cells to be empty if the attribute doesnt exist in that particular object

Comment: Then I would assume you still want it to return the attribute if the attribute does exist?

Comment: the answer is no for complicated reasons but your answer will be useful to someone else so thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `__getattribute__`:

```
class MyObject:
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return None  # or simply return
    
x = MyObject()
print(x.abc)
print(x.xyz)
```

output:

```
None
None
```

*NB. note that is might not work with all attributes, there are reserved words, e.g. `x.class`*

Answer (score 0):

No sure if I understood your question (not very good at english), but i think you could try using `hasattr` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) to check if the attribute exist and return wathever you want if it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

In case you still want the class to return actual attributes when they do exist, you could have `__getattribute__` catch attribute errors:

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        except AttributeError:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that if the attribute does actually exist that you'd want its value, therefore I propose:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return super(MyClass, self).__getattr__(name)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return None

mc = MyClass()

print(mc.a)
print(mc.b)
```

**Output:**

```
1
None
```